# What's wrong with multiple models in my single view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When this code runs, checkbox items are missing their labels, and any selection in a checkbox crashes/fails the page.

```
View (Index.cshtml)

@using stupidassTests.Models
@model  MyViewModel


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";


}

<h2>Password Input</h2>

<div>
<p>Enter Password</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("password")

    <button type="submit" value="Search"></button>
}

<p>@Model.input.passWord</p> <!--passWord is underlined with red because it conflicts with the List'model'-->

</div>

<h2>Checkbox</h2>

<div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <p>
            @Html.HiddenFor(n => n.inputCollection[i].Id)
            @Html.DisplayFor(n => n.inputCollection[i].Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(n => n.inputCollection[i].Name)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(n => n.inputCollection[i].Checked)
        </p>

    }

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />


    if (ViewBag.Values != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.Values)
        {
            <p>@item</p>
        }
    }



}
```

Model (FormInputs.cs):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public FormInputs input { get; set; }
    public List<FormInputs> inputCollection { get; set; }
    public bool isList { get; set; }
}
public class FormInputs
{
    public string passWord = "";


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public List<string> checkBox = new List<string>();


}
```

Controller (HomeController.cs):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return View();
    }



    [HttpGet, ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult PasswordInput(string password)
    {
        FormInputs pss = new FormInputs();

        pss.passWord = password;

        MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel() { input = pss, isList = false };

return this.View("Index", mvm);

    }





    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CheckBoxGet()
    {


        var list = new List<FormInputs>
        {
             new FormInputs { Id = 1, Name = "Aquafina", Checked = false },
        new FormInputs { Id = 2, Name = "Mulshi Springs", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 3, Name = "Alfa Blue", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 4, Name = "Atlas Premium", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 5, Name = "Bailley", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 6, Name = "Bisleri", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 7, Name = "Himalayan", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 8, Name = "Cool Valley", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 9, Name = "Dew Drops", Checked = false },
         new FormInputs { Id = 10, Name = "Dislaren", Checked = false },

 };
        MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel() { inputCollection = list, isList = true };
return this.View("Index", mvm);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckBoxPost(MyViewModel model)
    {


        var selected = model.inputCollection.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Name);
        //ViewBag.Values = String.Join(", ", list);
        ViewBag.Values = selected;

        MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel() { inputCollection = model.inputCollection, isList = true };

        return this.View("Index", mvm);
    }
```

The checkbox controller crashes with this error:

```
error: Model.input.passWord: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Your `MyViewModel` contains on fields, not properties (you need `{ get; set; }`) and the model in your view is `MyViewModel` which means the POST method needs to be `public ActionResult CheckBoxPost(MyViewModel model)`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke still getting the same errors, but I did successfully replaced what you recommended, let's chat please

Comment: link to chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112653/discussion-between-fluffywuffy-and-samghatak

Comment: Include the actual error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in your code. You will need to study a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430265299) or two about ASP.Net MVC. Otherwise, you will never end asking very simple questions, and finally get frustrated.

The following code will help you to keep going. Ideally, you want to keep GET and POST action method names to be same *which is **Index** in this case*, unless you have a valid reason.

The problem **model.input** is **null** is you did not instantiate it after post back.

```
// Remove Index, and rename PasswordInput to Index
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    FormInputs pss = new FormInputs();

    // pss.passWord = password;

    MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel { input = pss, isList = false };

    return View(mvm);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    var selected = model.inputCollection.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Name);
    //ViewBag.Values = String.Join(", ", list);
    ViewBag.Values = selected;

    model.input = new FormInputs(); // <-- You need to instantiate FormInputs
    model.inputCollection = model.inputCollection;
    model.isList = true;

    return View( model);
}
```